# Void app exit after second backbutton press on Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm newbie with Cordoba and now I'm making my first CSS-HTML-JS app just for learn. My app has two screens:

- Main list of persons
- Person profile

When I call the Android back button using:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton',backMain,false);
```

The app show the main list. Then I try to replace the first call with this function to exit when press the back on main list.

```
function backClose (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Do you want to close the app?',
        function(rsp)
        {
            if ( rsp == 2 )
            {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }else{
                return;
            };
        },
        'Close', 
        'No,Close'
    );
};

document.removeEventListener('backbutton',backMain,false);
document.addEventListener('backbutton',backClose,false);
```

On the main list when I press the back button ask me to exit. This is fine but when when I'm on the profile and press it, the app go to main and then ask me for exit.

How to set to the app to back to main list when press back button on profile without ask for exit?

Thanks for any help.

Here my full javascript code for this app:

```js
var app = (function() {

    var _timerPage = 0;
    var _page = {};
    var _backMain = function(){};

    function xLoadingIcon (sltr)
    {
        $(sltr).html('<div class="loading-icon"></div>');
    };

    function xPersonsList ()
    {
        var buttons = $('#persons-list-switch'), list = $('#persons-list');

        buttons.find('[rolid]').off('click tap').on('click top',function()
        {
            loadRol( $(this).attr('rolid') );
        });

        loadRol( buttons.find('[rolid]:eq(0)').attr('rolid') );
        document.removeEventListener('backbutton',_backMain,false);
        document.addEventListener('backbutton',backClose,false);

        function backClose (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            navigator.notification.confirm(
                '¿Quieres cerrar la aplicación?',
                function(rsp)
                {
                    if ( rsp == 2 )
                    {
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }else{
                        return;
                    };
                },
                'Salir', 
                'No,Cerrar'
            );
        };

        function loadRol (rolid)
        {
            buttons.find('[rolid]').removeClass('active');
            buttons.find('[rolid="' + rolid + '"]').addClass('active');
            xLoadingIcon(list);

            var rqs = {
                exe: 'rol_list',
                rolid: rolid
            };

            utilities.formPost({
                request: rqs,
                success: function(rsp)
                {
                    console.dir();

                    var htm = utilities.templateDOM({
                        template_selector: '#template-persons-list',
                        data: rsp.data
                    });

                    list.html(htm);
                }
            });
        };
    };

    function xPersonInfo (a)
    {
        var box = _page.profile, boxBio = box.find('#person-bio'), boxBack = box.find('#back-button');
        var username = a.getAttribute('username');

        xLoadingIcon(boxBio);
        box.scrollTop(0);

        clearTimeout(_timerPage);
        _timerPage = setTimeout(function()
        {
            _page.persons.css('left','-100%');
            _page.profile.css('left','0%');
        },300);

        var rqs = {
            exe: 'person_info',
            username: username
        };

        utilities.formPost({
            request: rqs,
            success: function(rsp)
            {
                var data = rsp.data;
                data.photo = data.photo ? '<div class="photo"><img src="' + data.photo + '" alt=""></div>' : '';

                var htm = utilities.templateDOM({
                    template_selector: '#template-person-bio',
                    data: data
                });

                boxBio.html(htm);
            }
        });

        boxBack.off('click tap').on('click tap',_backMain);
        document.addEventListener('backbutton',_backMain,false);
    };

    function xIni ()
    {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready',function()
        {
            _page.persons = $('#page-persons');
            _page.profile = $('#page-profile');

            _backMain = function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                _page.persons.css('left','0%');
                _page.profile.css('left','100%');
            };

            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#1F303F");
            $('#page-profile').bind('swipeleft swiperight',_backMain);
            xPersonsList();
        },false);
    };

    return {

        ini: xIni,

        personInfo: xPersonInfo

    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to remove your second listener after you add _backMain.

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton',_backMain,false);
document.removeEventListener('backbutton',backClose,false);
```